# Website image greyed out

Tags: google-chrome

It happens only in Chrome,

But as you can see the twitter button image is greyed out.

http://merrybadend.com/

So I wonder if something wrong in my code or is this a bug of Chrome?

I also did try to use the code in the DIV which the image is placed.

> display:block

But that doesn't work.

However other browsers don't have this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change image from CMYK to RGB.
That will solve the problem.

[The grey image, how it did look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyhOM.jpg)